# GMP constructor not recognized by compiler?

Tags: c++, gmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string input_name = argv[1];
    std::ifstream input;
    input.open(input_name.c_str());

    std::string line;
    while (input >> line)
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        mpz_t test(line, 16);
    }

    input.close();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this piece of code, I get the following error:

```
error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
         mpz_t test(line, 16);
                            ^
warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
warning: unused variable 'test' [-Wunused-variable]
         mpz_t test(line, 16);
               ^
```

What could be wrong? I use the `-lgmp` linker option and functions I tried (i.e. `mpz_init` are recognized without a problem).

Comment: I'm not familiar with GMP. Just off the error message, the compiler is telling you that `mpz_t` doesn't have a two-parameter constructor. What makes you believe it should?

Comment: On this site https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers I can find `Function: explicit mpz_class::mpz_class (const char *s, int base = 0)`

Comment: Is `mpz_t` the same thing as `mpz_class`? `mpz_t` is for C interface, not C++. Edit: and to use C++ interface, you need `gmpxx.h`, not `gmp.h`. See https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html

Comment: You are right, this solved it. Sorry for the stupid question.